# Is numjs the equivalent of numpy in javascript? What are its dependencies to work?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm writing the js equivalent of a python code to perform some operations on an image like numpy.std(rgb_channel).
The load of image and getting its data is done by opencv.js (https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d0/d84/tutorial_js_usage.html)

At the moment, I'm stuck to write this code:
`numpy.std(image, axis=2)` which calculates stanadard deviation of rgb channel of an image.

My question is : for writing this code in javascript, should I use numjs node module? I, also, got the source code of numjs (https://github.com/nicolaspanel/numjs).
Here is the std function in numjs:

```
NdArray.prototype.std = function (options) {
  options = _.defaults(options, { 'ddof': 0 });
  var squares = this.clone();
  ops.powseq(squares.selection, 2);
  var mean = this.mean();
  var shapeSize = _.shapeSize(this.shape);
  var variance = ops.sum(squares.selection) / (shapeSize - options.ddof) - mean * mean * shapeSize / (shapeSize - options.ddof);

  return variance > 0 ? Math.sqrt(Math.abs(variance)) : 0;
};
```

Another question would be: some errors were thrown for installing numjs like: gyp ERR! stack Error
and errors related to MSBuild.exe and also not find python. If numjs is a pure js code, why these packages should be installed. By the way, I installed python, MSBuild.exe 2017 (according to https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-gyp), still get a bunch of errors like:
sharp node module (`npm ERR! Failed at the sharp@0.20.8 install script.`)
and
`` gyp ERR! stack Error: `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual 
Studio\2017\BuildTools\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\MSBuild.exe` failed with exit code: 1 ``

Comment: For what it's worth half a year later, it seems that sharp requires node 10.

Comment: I'd love to see what you're working on! I'm also putting something together, though it's not meant to be an alternative to numpy. I'd like to collect some Numpy functions in JavaScript for my library. Or even better - collaborate and merge our libraries! Feel free to copy my code. What is your project called? https://github.com/paulshorey/pauls-pure-functions

Answer (score 0):

`numjs`' dependencies are listed here, https://www.npmjs.com/package/numjs. Most of them are pure JavaScript but `sharp` is using some native code (so you see gyp compilation error) and is used in the image processing feature of `numjs`.

If you do not need this `numjs`' feature, you can consider https://www.npmjs.com/package/@d4c/numjs which is published by me. It removes that image processing feature which may cause installation errors, and add some TypeScript typing.

And to answer your original questions, it is a lighter version of `NumPy` in JavaScript and some of `NumPy` functions are not supplied.